# Placing two div's, of unequal width, with margin, paddding and border, side by side

Tags: html, css

I want to place two `div`s side by side. However, I don't want them to be equal in width; I want the first `div` to take up 70% of the space and the second one to fill the rest of the space.

So far I have this code (or see [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkpxj/)):

HTML

```
<div id='d1' class='bodyRect'>
    div 1
</div>
<div id='d2' class='bodyRect'>
    div 2
</div>
<span class='clearfix'></span>
```

CSS

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
.bodyRect {
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /*behavior: url(/PIE.htc); /* CSS PIE - for IE 6-8 */
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
#d1 {
    width: 70%; float: left
}
#d2 {
    width: 30%; float: right
}
.clearfix {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

However, that results in this:

[image]

Only after removing the `margin`, `padding`, **and** `border` do the `div`s align correctly.

How can I make this work while still keeping the `margin`, `padding`, and `border`?

It needs to support IE8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Separate the padding and margin from the parent `<DIV>` by placing a child within. It will fill the width of parent, but the margin and padding are subtracted from the width of the parent (instead of added to it). This results in a true 70% and 29% `<DIV>`s, with padding and margin inside.

Here is a link to the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wkpxj/5/

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id='d1' class='bodyRect'><div>
    div 1
</div></div>
<div id='d2' class='bodyRect'><div>
    div 2
</div></div>
<span class='clearfix'></span>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
.bodyRect { /* move all stylings to the child */
}

.bodyRect > div { /* apply padding and margin to the direct descendent */
    border: 1px solid black; /* apply border here to respect margin */
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /*behavior: url(/PIE.htc); /* CSS PIE - for IE 6-8 */

    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}

#d1 {
    width: 70%; float: left
}
#d2 {
    width: 29%; float: right /* <100% to allow for border */
}
.clearfix {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you post a JSFiddle?

Comment: Thanks, but that gives no margin though.

Comment: You can apply the border to the descendent, instead, which will respect margin and apply border: http://jsfiddle.net/wkpxj/5/

Comment: Aha! That works! Thanks! (can accept your answer in 3 minutes)

Comment: Also note that it still works with `width: 30%` instead of `width: 29%`.

Comment: Actually 1. PIE is commented out and 2. PIE only affects IE6-8

Comment: Oh! I thought you were resting on IE8. But because it's within the parent, you can go the full 100. Duh!

Answer (score 0):

The most semantic solution to this problem, which I'll describe here, is only supported in IE9+. For deeper IE support, refer to Set Sail's answer. I know the asker needs IE8+ support, but I just thought that I'd put this answer here in case other programmers find this question who have less stringent requirements.

I like this answer because it doesn't require any additional markup; it keeps the styling completely contained in the Css.

[**View the solution on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/E6kBa/)

We do two things here:

#### 1. [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing): border-box;

What this does is calculate the width of the divs to include the `border` and `padding`, but not the margin.

#### 2. width: [calc();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

And what this does is allow us to write equations to calculate widths. In this case, we subtract `20px` from the width of both of our `div`s, as they both have a left and right margin of `10px` each.

### The Css

```
.bodyRect {
  ...
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
#d1 {
  width: -webkit-calc(70% - 20px);
  width: -moz-calc(70% - 20px);
  width: calc(70% - 20px);
  float: left
}
#d2 {
  width: -webkit-calc(30% - 20px);
  width: -moz-calc(30% - 20px);
  width: calc(30% - 20px);
  float: right
}
```

Comment: @Doorknob; I've updated the answer. It isn't useful to you, given your particular constraints, but I prefer this answer on semantic grounds when browser support isn't as big as a necessity.

Answer (score 0):

### How can I make this work while still keeping the `margin`, `padding`, and `border`?

The `margin`, `padding`, and `border` take up some of the space. If you set your widths to something lower, you'll see that the divs are side-by-side: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkpxj/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the float in this case. You can achieve the placement next to each other by putting `display: inline-block`.

The reason the why you have trouble displaying them next to each other are the margins which are **not** part of the width.

```
.bodyRect {
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /*behavior: url(/PIE.htc); /* CSS PIE - for IE 6-8 */
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
#d1 {
    width: 50%; 
    display: inline-block;
}
#d2 {
    width: 29%; 
    display: inline-block;
}
```